# Как заполнить экран повторяющейся текстурой TiledDrawable для Stage?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить такую проблему. 
Нужно заполнить экран повторяющейся текстурой. 
Собственно, вопрос в том, как использовать TiledDrawable совместно с использованием Stage?
Собственно, вот код, который не работает:

```
public LevelsScreen (final TriangleGame gam) {
    game = gam;
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    TiledDrawable background = new TiledDrawable(game.levelScreen); // game.LevelScreen = AtlasRegion
    background.draw(stage.getBatch(), 0, 0, stage.getWidth() / 2, stage.getWidth() / 2);
}
```

На StackOverflow уже видел ответ, который вроде как должен решить проблему: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934212

Но вместо заполнения экрана текстурой, отрисовывается чёрный прямоугольник внизу экрана. Да и выглядит этот код не особо привлекательно. Уверен, что должны быть более "элегантные" способы.

Благодарен за Ваши ответы.

Answer (score 0):

```
public LevelsScreen (final TriangleGame gam) {
    game = gam;
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

TiledDrawable background = 
skin.getTiledDrawable("file_name");
background.draw(stage.getBatch(), 0, 0, stage.getWidth() 
    / 2, stage.getWidth() / 2);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]